# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset only in android 9

Tags: java, android, android-9.0-pie

I've get `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` when trying to send GET request. The problem is that same code I use works fine in Android 8 and loweer but don't work in Android 9. Also, this problems happens only on some reuquests in my app, not all. This lib is used for HTTP requests: https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request

I've already added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to manifest, but it not helps.

Here is some code I use to send request:

```
    String response = "";

    args.put("InvokationTarget", methodName);
    args.put("DepartmentId", String.valueOf(departmentId));

    try {
        if (mWebServiceUrl != null) {
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.get(mWebServiceUrl, args, true);

            Log.i(TAG, "Request: " + request.toString());
            long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (request.ok()) {
                response = request.body(HttpRequest.CHARSET_UTF8);

                long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - ts;
                Log.i(TAG, "Response: " + response);
                Log.i(TAG, "Duration: " + (delta / 1000.0) + " sec.");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(e);
        response = e.getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a [networkSecurityConfig](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                    ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**network_security_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: No exceptions now, thanks. But nothing happens after method call and I can't recieve response